# pd.read_html is returning the table as a dataframe with a single column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to scrape the empty table in this sec filing to confirm that it is indeed empty in the sense there is numeric value for the PER SHARE or TOTAL column. The table is not getting scraped properly. Every column of the table ends up as a single series of the dataframe or a single column. The output should be a dataframe with multiple columns. Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/0001509190/000150919017000022/petx-20170503x8k.htm

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from urllib.request import urlopen, Request

url =  'https://www.sec.gov/Archives/edgar/data/0001509190/000150919017000022/petx-20170503x8k.htm'
req = Request(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
webpage = urlopen(req).read()
soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage, 'lxml')

table = soup.find_all('table', limit = 5)
df = pd.read_html(str(table))
df1 = df[0]
print(df1)
```

Comment: it worked for me

Comment: maybe try a different parser?  `html.parser` instead of `lxml`